# Build.Gradle (Module App) is converted to auto generated file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Build.Gradle (Module App) is converted to auto generated file, please help me to revert back to gradle.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step to get your code

->  Right-click in build.gradle file

->  Select option on show local history

You will get all the previous code with date and time..